# How to write a code to loop a designated class

Tags: python, class

I am working on writing a code that creates a class named car.
within the class I need to track an odometer, speed, driver name, and sponsor.
I believe that the code for the class itself is correct, however I am trying to create 20 cars to participate in a race, but when I try to loop it It only creates one. what am I doing wrong.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
from random import randint

class car:
   odometer = 0
   speed = randint(1,120)
   driver = input("Drivers name:")
   sponsor = input("Car Sponsor:")
part_cars = 0
while (part_cars < int(20)):
   car
   part_cars += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `car` is just a class and you need to initialize it. Maybe this code is better:

```
from random import randint

class Car:
    def __init__(self, odometer, speed, driver, sponsor):
        self.odometer = odometer
        self.speed = speed
        self.driver = driver
        self.sponsor = sponsor

cars = []
while len(cars) < 20:
    speed = randint(1, 120)
    driver = input("Drivers name:")
    sponsor = input("Car sponsor:")
    cars.append(Car(0, speed, driver, sponsor))
```

And taking a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) may help you understand class better.

Comment: thanks for the help I didn't even notice I hadn't initialized it. This code is definitely more effective